# What's the hotkey for going to last modified place in xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, ide, xcode4

I've used control+command+left, but it goes to the last modified file, not the last modified line in this file.
Anyone knows the hotkey for going to last modified place in xcode4? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a direct way to do this, but I use a command+z and ctrl+command+z to take me to the last modified location. (Undo/Redo in short, but works no matter where you are)

Comment: redo should be cmd + shift + z